# Using gcc to compile a C program

Tags: c, gcc, shebang

I am following an example from CUNY and I have never done anything with C before so I probably don't know what I am doing.

Consider the program below.

1. Do I need a shebang line for C code written in emacs?
2. When I go to compile using the line `gcc -g -o forwardadding forwardadding.c`
   I am hit with the message:

   ```
   forwardadding.c:9:17: error: expected expression before ‘<’ token
   ```
3. Once I get the code compiles, I can use gdb to debug and run the code corrrect?

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

main()
{
    float sum, term;
    int i;
    sum = 0.0;
    for( i = 1; < 10000000; i++)
    {
        term = (float) i;
        term = term * term;
        term = 1 / term;
        sum += term;
    }
    printf("The sum is %.12f\n", sum);
}
```

Comment: Shebangs (`#!` on line 1) are used only for scripts; they tell the system what interpreter to use. Since a C source files is not executed or interpreted, a shebang would be neither necessary nor appropriate. (The generated executable also doesn't need a `#!` line, since it's executed directly, not interpreted.)

Comment: Please compile with `gcc -Wall -g` (all warnings & debugging information) and improve the code till no warnings are given; then learn to use `gdb` for debugging.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to put a variable in the for loop for a complete expression (which is probably line 9...)

```
for( i = 1; < 10000000; i++)
```

change to this

```
for( i = 1; i < 10000000; i++)
```

Answer (score 9):

1. No shebang is needed.  You could add an Emacs mode line comment.
2. The `for` loop should be:

   ```
   for (i = 1; i < 10000000; i++)
   ```

   Your code is missing the second `i`.
3. Yes, you can use GDB once you've got the code compiling.

You'd get a better answer to the mathematics if you counted down from 10,000,000 than by counting up to 10,000,000.  After about `i = 10000`, the extra values add nothing to the result.

Please get into the habit of writing C99 code.  That means you should write:

```
int main(void)
```

with the return type of `int` being required and the `void` being recommended.

Comment: what is C99 code?  wouldn't the answer being returned be a float?

Comment: C99 is the old standard for C, ISO/IEC 9899:1999; the new standard is C2011, and the very old standard is C89. C89 allowed you to write `main()` without the explicit return type of `int`; C99 removed that permission, but many compilers still recognize and allow it unless you tell them that the code is to be compiled to the C99 standard (`-std=c99` in GCC). I compile habitually with `gcc -O3 -g -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition`, often with `-Werror` so any warning is treated as an error, and my code compiles cleanly under those flags.

Comment: @JonathonLeffler backward adding the same series is next

Comment: Given the file name, I'm not surprised to hear that 'backward adding' is next.  Will you also be trying with `double` in place of `float`?  It would be a good idea too (both forwards and backwards).

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an an `i`. Just correct that as Jonathan Leffler has suggested and save your file. Open your terminal and just use this to compile your code `gcc your_file_name.c` and your code compiles next to run the code that just compiled type `./a.out` and your program runs and shows you the output.

Comment: Use `gcc -Wall -g your_file_name.c -o your_program` to compile `your_file_name.c` into the `your_program` binary (which you would run as `./your_program`); you really want all warnings and debugging information from `gcc`